# WPF DataContext not forwarded through a custom control down the control tree

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, viewbox

I need a layout control similar to a Viewbox but with slightly different stretching rules. I copied the Viewbox sources from the .NET reference source, but now I see weird data binding issues in child controls.

Here is a simplified example:

```
<Window
    x:Class="CustomViewbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomViewbox"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
>
    <local:Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=Round,StringFormat={}Round {0}}"/>
                <Button Margin="5" Content="Next round" Click="next_round_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </local:Viewbox>
</Window>
```

And the corresponding code-behind:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace CustomViewbox
{
    public class Game : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }

        int round = 1;
        public int Round { get { return round; } set { round = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Game game;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            game = new Game();
            DataContext = game;
        }

        private void next_round_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ++game.Round;
        }
    }
}
```

When running that, the TextBlock is empty or invisible (not collapsed). So far I've found 3 unsatisfactory workarounds:

- if I replace local:Viewbox with just Viewbox, the layout is wrong
- if I remove the Foreground attribute from the TextBlock, the text is the wrong color
- finally if I add the attribute DataContext="{Binding}" to the TextBlock, it looks OK, but this doesn't feel like a proper fix

Can someone explain what is going on, or how to debug that?

For completeness here is the modified Viewbox source code, which should be all the code you need to reproduce my problem:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace CustomViewbox
{
    public class Viewbox : Decorator
    {
        private ContainerVisual _internalVisual;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StretchProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Stretch", typeof(Stretch), typeof(Viewbox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Stretch.Uniform, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure), new ValidateValueCallback(ValidateStretchValue));
        private static bool ValidateStretchValue(object value)
        {
            var s = (Stretch)value;
            return s == Stretch.Uniform
                || s == Stretch.None
                || s == Stretch.Fill
                || s == Stretch.UniformToFill;
        }

        private ContainerVisual InternalVisual
        {
            get
            {
                if (_internalVisual == null)
                {
                    _internalVisual = new ContainerVisual();
                    AddVisualChild(_internalVisual);
                }
                return _internalVisual;
            }
        }

        private UIElement InternalChild
        {
            get
            {
                VisualCollection vc = InternalVisual.Children;
                if (vc.Count != 0) return vc[0] as UIElement;
                else return null;
            }
            set
            {
                VisualCollection vc = InternalVisual.Children;
                if (vc.Count != 0) vc.Clear();
                vc.Add(value);
            }
        }

        private Transform InternalTransform
        {
            get
            {
                return InternalVisual.Transform;
            }
            set
            {
                InternalVisual.Transform = value;
            }
        }

        public override UIElement Child
        {
            // everything is the same as on Decorator, the only difference is to insert intermediate Visual to specify scaling transform
            get
            {
                return InternalChild;
            }

            set
            {
                UIElement old = InternalChild;

                if (old != value)
                {
                    //need to remove old element from logical tree
                    RemoveLogicalChild(old);

                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        AddLogicalChild(value);
                    }

                    InternalChild = value;

                    InvalidateMeasure();
                }
            }
        }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get { return 1; /* Always have internal container visual */ }
        }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            if (index != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", index, /*SR.Get(SRID.Visual_ArgumentOutOfRange)*/"argument out of range");
            }
            return InternalVisual;
        }

        public Stretch Stretch
        {
            get { return (Stretch)GetValue(StretchProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StretchProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates DesiredSize of the Viewbox.  Called by parent UIElement.  This is the first pass of layout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Viewbox measures it's child at an infinite constraint; it allows the child to be however large it so desires.
        /// The child's returned size will be used as it's natural size for scaling to Viewbox's size during Arrange.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="constraint">Constraint size is an "upper limit" that the return value should not exceed.</param>
        /// <returns>The Decorator's desired size.</returns>
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            var child = InternalChild;
            var parentSize = new Size();

            if (child != null)
            {
                // Initialize child constraint to infinity.  We need to get a "natural" size for the child in absence of constraint.
                // Note that an author *can* impose a constraint on a child by using Height/Width, &c... properties 
                var infiniteConstraint = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);

                child.Measure(infiniteConstraint);
                var childSize = child.DesiredSize;

                var scalefac = ComputeScaleFactor(constraint, childSize, Stretch);

                parentSize.Width = scalefac * childSize.Width;
                parentSize.Height = scalefac * childSize.Height;

                if (parentSize.Width > constraint.Width)
                    parentSize.Width = constraint.Width;

                childSize = new Size(constraint.Width / scalefac, constraint.Height / scalefac);
                child.Measure(childSize);
            }

            return parentSize;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Viewbox always sets the child to its desired size.  It then computes and applies a transformation
        /// from that size to the space available: Viewbox's own input size less child margin.
        /// 
        /// Viewbox also calls arrange on its child.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="arrangeSize">Size in which Border will draw the borders/background and children.</param>
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
        {
            var child = InternalChild;
            if (child != null)
            {
                var childSize = child.DesiredSize;

                // Compute scaling factors from arrange size and the measured child content size
                var scalefac = ComputeScaleFactor(arrangeSize, childSize, Stretch);

                InternalTransform = new ScaleTransform(scalefac, scalefac);

                childSize = new Size(arrangeSize.Width / scalefac, arrangeSize.Height / scalefac);

                // Arrange the child to the desired size 
                child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), childSize));

                // return the size occupied by scaled child
                arrangeSize.Width = scalefac * childSize.Width;
                arrangeSize.Height = scalefac * childSize.Height;
            }
            return arrangeSize;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is a helper function that computes scale factors depending on a target size and a content size
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="availableSize">Size into which the content is being fitted.</param>
        /// <param name="contentSize">Size of the content, measured natively (unconstrained).</param>
        /// <param name="stretch">Value of the Stretch property on the element.</param>
        internal static double ComputeScaleFactor(Size availableSize, Size contentSize, Stretch stretch)
        {
            // Compute scaling factors to use for axes
            var scale = 1.0;

            var isConstrainedHeight = !Double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height);

            if (isConstrainedHeight)
            {
                // Compute scaling factors for both axes
                scale = (DoubleUtil.IsZero(contentSize.Height)) ? 0.0 : availableSize.Height / contentSize.Height;
            }

            return scale;
        }
    }

    static class DoubleUtil
    {
        internal const double DBL_EPSILON = 2.2204460492503131e-016; /* smallest such that 1.0+DBL_EPSILON != 1.0 */
        internal const float FLT_MIN = 1.175494351e-38F; /* Number close to zero, where float.MinValue is -float.MaxValue */

        public static bool IsZero(double value)
        {
            return Math.Abs(value) < 10.0 * DBL_EPSILON;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I compared your code to the reference source - a notable difference is that you do not override the LogicalChildren property.

Comment: What exactly are these "*slightly different stretching rules*"? Maybe there is an easier way to achieve them.

Comment: To elaborate on Klaus' point. DataContext is marked as inherits and thus is inherited down the logical tree. Overriding LogicalChildren sounds like it might be necessary for that process to work. IIRC a DP on any children also has to be marked Inherits for inherits to work.  I've never found a need to subtype viewbox myself. What's "wrong" with a regular viewbox?

Comment: I think I need a custom viewbox because I want to preserve the child desired height (so it fits the Window vertically) but ignore its desired width (I want uniform scaling, and the child width should adapt to the windows aspect ratio).

Comment: @KlausGütter I removed the LogicalChildren override because it's internal. I can't override it in my own class, right?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was the missing override of LogicalChildren in the Viewbox class, as suggested by [Klaus Gütter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165786/wpf-datacontext-not-forwarded-through-a-custom-control-down-the-control-tree/54174823#comment95163295_54165786). I wrongly assumed one cannot override an internal property, so I removed it. But it turns out I can as long as I remove the internal keyword from my override.

Here is the working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace CustomViewbox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an Enumerator that enumerates over nothing.
    /// </summary>
    internal class EmptyEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        // singleton class, private ctor
        private EmptyEnumerator()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Read-Only instance of an Empty Enumerator.
        /// </summary>
        public static IEnumerator Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new EmptyEnumerator();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Does nothing.
        /// </summary>
        public void Reset() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>false</returns>
        public bool MoveNext() { return false; }


#pragma warning disable 1634, 1691  // about to use PreSharp message numbers - unknown to C#

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns null.
        /// </summary>
        public object Current
        {
            get
            {
#pragma warning disable 6503 // "Property get methods should not throw exceptions."

                throw new InvalidOperationException();

#pragma warning restore 6503
            }
        }
#pragma warning restore 1634, 1691

        private static IEnumerator _instance;
    }

    internal class SingleChildEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        internal SingleChildEnumerator(object Child)
        {
            _child = Child;
            _count = Child == null ? 0 : 1;
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return (_index == 0) ? _child : null; }
        }

        bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
        {
            _index++;
            return _index < _count;
        }

        void IEnumerator.Reset()
        {
            _index = -1;
        }

        private int _index = -1;
        private int _count = 0;
        private object _child;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public class Viewbox : Decorator
    {

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Constructors
        //
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Constructors

        /*static Viewbox()
        {
            ControlsTraceLogger.AddControl(TelemetryControls.ViewBox);
        }*/

        /// <summary>
        ///     Default DependencyObject constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        ///     Automatic determination of current Dispatcher. Use alternative constructor
        ///     that accepts a Dispatcher for best performance.
        /// </remarks>
        public Viewbox() : base()
        {
        }

        #endregion


        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Public Fields
        //
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Public Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the DependencyProperty for the Viewbox's Stretch property.
        ///
        /// Default:  Stretch.Uniform
        /// <seealso cref="Viewbox.Stretch" />
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StretchProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Stretch",          // Property name
                typeof(Stretch),    // Property type
                typeof(Viewbox),    // Property owner
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Stretch.Uniform, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure),
                new ValidateValueCallback(ValidateStretchValue));

        private static bool ValidateStretchValue(object value)
        {
            Stretch s = (Stretch)value;
            return (s == Stretch.Uniform
                    || s == Stretch.None
                    || s == Stretch.Fill
                    || s == Stretch.UniformToFill);
        }

        #endregion


        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Public Methods
        //
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Public Properties
        //
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Public Properties

        private ContainerVisual InternalVisual
        {
            get
            {
                if (_internalVisual == null)
                {
                    _internalVisual = new ContainerVisual();
                    AddVisualChild(_internalVisual);
                }
                return _internalVisual;
            }
        }

        private UIElement InternalChild
        {
            get
            {
                VisualCollection vc = InternalVisual.Children;
                if (vc.Count != 0) return vc[0] as UIElement;
                else return null;
            }
            set
            {
                VisualCollection vc = InternalVisual.Children;
                if (vc.Count != 0) vc.Clear();
                vc.Add(value);
            }
        }

        private Transform InternalTransform
        {
            get
            {
                return InternalVisual.Transform;
            }
            set
            {
                InternalVisual.Transform = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The single child of a <see cref="Viewbox" />
        /// </summary>
        public override UIElement Child
        {
            //everything is the same as on Decorator, the only difference is to insert intermediate Visual to
            //specify scaling transform
            get
            {
                return InternalChild;
            }

            set
            {
                UIElement old = InternalChild;

                if (old != value)
                {
                    //need to remove old element from logical tree
                    RemoveLogicalChild(old);

                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        AddLogicalChild(value);
                    }

                    InternalChild = value;

                    InvalidateMeasure();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Visual children count.
        /// </summary>
        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get { return 1; /* Always have internal container visual */ }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the child at the specified index.
        /// </summary>
        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            if (index != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(/*"index", index, SR.Get(SRID.Visual_ArgumentOutOfRange)*/);
            }
            return InternalVisual;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns enumerator to logical children.
        /// </summary>
        protected override IEnumerator LogicalChildren
        {
            get
            {
                if (InternalChild == null)
                {
                    return EmptyEnumerator.Instance;
                }

                return new SingleChildEnumerator(InternalChild);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/Sets the Stretch mode of the Viewbox, which determines how the content will be
        /// fit into the Viewbox's space.
        ///
        /// </summary>
        /// <seealso cref="Viewbox.StretchProperty" />
        /// <seealso cref="Stretch" />
        public Stretch Stretch
        {
            get { return (Stretch)GetValue(StretchProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StretchProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion Public Properties

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Protected Methods
        //
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Protected Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates DesiredSize of the Viewbox.  Called by parent UIElement.  This is the first pass of layout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Viewbox measures it's child at an infinite constraint; it allows the child to be however large it so desires.
        /// The child's returned size will be used as it's natural size for scaling to Viewbox's size during Arrange.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="constraint">Constraint size is an "upper limit" that the return value should not exceed.</param>
        /// <returns>The Decorator's desired size.</returns>
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            var child = InternalChild;
            var parentSize = new Size();

            if (child != null)
            {
                // Initialize child constraint to infinity.  We need to get a "natural" size for the child in absence of constraint.
                // Note that an author *can* impose a constraint on a child by using Height/Width, &c... properties 
                var infiniteConstraint = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);

                child.Measure(infiniteConstraint);
                var childSize = child.DesiredSize;

                var scalefac = ComputeScaleFactor(constraint, childSize, Stretch);

                parentSize.Width = scalefac * childSize.Width;
                parentSize.Height = scalefac * childSize.Height;

                if (parentSize.Width > constraint.Width)
                    parentSize.Width = constraint.Width;

                childSize = new Size(constraint.Width / scalefac, constraint.Height / scalefac);
                child.Measure(childSize);
            }

            return parentSize;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Viewbox always sets the child to its desired size.  It then computes and applies a transformation
        /// from that size to the space available: Viewbox's own input size less child margin.
        /// 
        /// Viewbox also calls arrange on its child.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="arrangeSize">Size in which Border will draw the borders/background and children.</param>
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
        {
            var child = InternalChild;
            if (child != null)
            {
                var childSize = child.DesiredSize;

                // Compute scaling factors from arrange size and the measured child content size
                var scalefac = ComputeScaleFactor(arrangeSize, childSize, Stretch);

                InternalTransform = new ScaleTransform(scalefac, scalefac);

                childSize = new Size(arrangeSize.Width / scalefac, arrangeSize.Height / scalefac);

                // Arrange the child to the desired size 
                child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), childSize));

                // return the size occupied by scaled child
                arrangeSize.Width = scalefac * childSize.Width;
                arrangeSize.Height = scalefac * childSize.Height;
            }
            return arrangeSize;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is a helper function that computes scale factors depending on a target size and a content size
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="availableSize">Size into which the content is being fitted.</param>
        /// <param name="contentSize">Size of the content, measured natively (unconstrained).</param>
        /// <param name="stretch">Value of the Stretch property on the element.</param>
        internal static double ComputeScaleFactor(Size availableSize, Size contentSize, Stretch stretch)
        {
            // Compute scaling factors to use for axes
            var scale = 1.0;

            var isConstrainedHeight = !Double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height);

            if (isConstrainedHeight)
            {
                // Compute scaling factors for both axes
                scale = (DoubleUtil.IsZero(contentSize.Height)) ? 0.0 : availableSize.Height / contentSize.Height;
            }

            return scale;
        }

        #endregion Protected Methods



        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Private Fields
        //
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Private Fields

        private ContainerVisual _internalVisual;

        #endregion


    }

    static class DoubleUtil
    {
        internal const double DBL_EPSILON = 2.2204460492503131e-016; /* smallest such that 1.0+DBL_EPSILON != 1.0 */
        internal const float FLT_MIN = 1.175494351e-38F; /* Number close to zero, where float.MinValue is -float.MaxValue */

        public static bool IsZero(double value)
        {
            return Math.Abs(value) < 10.0 * DBL_EPSILON;
        }
    }
}
```